# Is there a standard style for writing chapter notes in a non-fiction book manuscript?

Tags: formatting, citations, non-fiction

I am trying to find a standard style for writing chapter notes in a non-academic non-fiction book as per the image below. Is there an online resource where I can find an appropriate style guide for this?

[image: Picture of the first page of chapter notes from the book 'Who Owns England' by Guy Shrubsole]

Comment: Such "mechanical" style issues will depend where you want to publish. There is no absolute correct style that will be accepted everywhere. Check with that place, such persons as an editor or the teacher of a class. Look for a style guide. Look for how previous authors have done things.